# How to use a pre-trained model in Flux.jl?

Tags: neural-network, julia, flux.jl

I'm using the Flux library in Julia. How can I import an Inception neural network into it?

I've seen that the following can be done in `Mocha.jl` to import a pre-trained net.

```
using HDF5
h5open("model/bvlc_reference_caffenet.hdf5", "r") do h5
    load_network(h5, net)
end
init(net)
```

Is there some way I can import a pre-trained model in `Flux`?

Comment: xref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-import-a-pre-trained-neural-network-into-flux-jl/9659

Comment: This is discussed in [the documentation](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/saving/)

Comment: The docs only show how to do it with one filetype right now, I image the scope of this question is beyond that